# HTML/CSS: Link Styling being used for image hyperlinks, and I can't get it to stop?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am adding links to images and I can not remove the a:link style and a:hover style that is designated for my text links.

I added in a new .css style for a.button:link and a.button:hover,

```
#content a.button:link {
     text-decoration:none;
     }
#content a.button:hover {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

and set the

```
<a href="www.website.com" class="button"><img></img></a>
```

but it STILL uses the default  styling! I'm being drove insane. I have checked different websites, and they ALL say to simply use a class="nameofclass" after the href, BUT it doesn't work for me on my site(s) when using images.

as requested JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aqtq2gq4/1/

Comment: Are you using this <a> tag inside #content?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aqtq2gq4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "natural" behavior of an anchor tag is just a link that contains text, right? So when you are adding this anchor tag for the img, the rectangle you're seeing is the browser "preparing" for the text, so it is taking a height of the default font size.

The trick is to make the font size for the .button class 0px, remove the padding, and remove the border, and Voila!

```
#content a.button:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}

#content a.button:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
}
```

This will add the opacity to the img:

```
#content a.button > img:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

I hope this is what you wanted!

Here is an updated fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/aqtq2gq4/8/

Comment: The important note did not change.

What do you mean by the html tag?

Comment: Really surprised that important didn't work.  I thought for sure you were being overridden somewhere.

If you create a fiddle I might have a better idea of what you're trying to do.  Something tells me there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here is the info!  The #content is for my HTML chain, it defines this is my content block.  I hand coded my entire site using div id's I have a wrapper, then within the wrapper I add in the header, navigation, or content ID as it has styling set to it.  It works really well besides this issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/aqtq2gq4/1/

Comment: resolved? I am not sure what your images are supposed to look like because your images are linking to a local directory on your computer, not on the internet.

Comment: Do you see how the images have the rectangle under them? That needs to be gone.  You can see this rectangle under the image placeholder location. For comparison I added what my normal link styling is. It is applying to my images with links EVEN THOUGH I change the class style?

Comment: I figured it out. Give me a couple of minutes I am putting together a fresh fiddle for you with comments to help you learn.

Comment: Please check out the fiddle in my solution and let me know if that works.  Here is link again:  https://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/aqtq2gq4/7/

Comment: Haha, that worked! I am glad I was on the right track. Thanks a lot.  Now I was wanting to add a hover feature so the end user knows the images are clickable. This was easiest achieved with opacity: 0.8; for example.  What is the css image code I would use for this, because adding it under a.button:hover did not effect on hovering like I figured.

Comment: Can you upvote my solution? Sorry I'm not sure if you're even able to.  I am new to SO too

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation but I think I can choose it as the answer.  You and war1oc both had solutions.  If you have any input on the image opacity detail, I'd love to add that in just to have it be a bit more interactive. EDIT: Nvm, used a.img:hover to fix it.

Comment: Glad I could help out! Let me know if you ever need anything.

Comment: Ah, that works too. Thanks.  What is the code reading to make it know "a.button > img:hover" becomes "a.img:hover" in terms of the code? Does the > achieve that?

Comment: div p{} would select any <p> element that is inside a div, no matter how many layers deep.  div > p{} will select <p> elements whose immediate parent is a div.

So in this case, the > isn't really necessary, but it's a little more specfifc just in case.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand, you have two separate types of links, text and img, and want them to be styled differently. In your fiddle though, the css you're using applies the styles to all 'a' tags and thus the problem at hand. In my opinion you should have separate classes for the two 'a' types.

https://jsfiddle.net/aqtq2gq4/5/

Here is the fiddle in which I have put the text link in class "textLink"

```
<td><center><a href="http://www.website.com/" class="textLink">Text Link</a></center></td>
```

and the image links are in "button" class (as they were before, change them to "imageLink" or whatever you prefer)

```
<td><center><a href="http://www.website.com/" class="button"><img src="images/midland_button.png" width="238" height="86" alt="Midland" /></a></center></td>
```

and then applied the styles individually

```
#content a.textLink:link {
    color:#CC0000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 3px 3px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
#content a.textLink:hover {
    color:#0CF;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px dashed;
    padding: 3px 3px;
    background-color:#282D57;
}
#content a.button:link {

}
#content a.button:hover {

}
```

Comment: Yes. I tried that before, no difference... it seems the a:link feature is over-writing any a href style

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Comment: @LeaCohen, thanks i have updated my answer and also included a jsfiddle link to demonstrate.

Comment: @Nic can u pls post a fiddle link to show whats going wrong?

Comment: @war1oc, plushyObject was able to get it sorted with the font size and padding feature. I appreciate your time! Your method also works, I was trying to not have to set a style for the text link and just let it be my default. Using plushy's method, I can keep it the same. I will keep your idea in mind if I end up having to put many links on this website, though.